# jQquery validation engine で、２つの項目のうちどちらか片方が入力された場合、両方を必須にするには

Tags: jquery

お世話になります。

現在開発中のフォームに２つのテキスト(input type="text")項目があります。

これらの項目のうち、片方が入力されると、もう片方も入力しないとエラーになるようにしたいのですが方法が分かりません。

環境は、jQuery validation engine です。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: チェックしたいタイミングでそれぞれのtextboxの値を取って、どっちかに値が入ってる状態でもう一方が空だったらngで、そうじゃなかったらokとすれば良いです。

Answer (score 1):

[こちらのサイト](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/)内にある [groupRequired](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#grouprequired)の例か、または [condRequired](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#condrequired)の例どちらかで満たせるかと思います。